# JasperReport export to pdf not working

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I have the following controller to export a report as `pdf, xls, csv`. The code for it is given below

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = ServicePath.COMMON_PREFIX + "/test-report")
public class ReportController 
{

@Autowired
private UserService userService;

public static JasperDesign jasperDesign;
public static JasperPrint jasperPrint;
public static JasperReport jasperReport;
public static String reportTemplateUrl = "/lms-internet/src/main/webapp/report.jrxml";

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET , value = "/pdf")
public void generatePdf()
{
    try{
    List<User> usersList = userService.findAll();

    JRDataSource JRdataSource = new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(usersList);

    InputStream resourceAsStream = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader()
            .getResourceAsStream(reportTemplateUrl);
    //get report file and then load into jasperDesign
    jasperDesign = JRXmlLoader.load(resourceAsStream);
    //compile the jasperDesign
    jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(jasperDesign);

    ByteArrayOutputStream output = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    OutputStream outputfile = new FileOutputStream(new File("c:/temp/person.xls"));

    HashMap params = new HashMap();

    //fill the ready report with data and parameter
    jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, params, JRdataSource);

    //coding for Excel
    JRXlsExporter exporterXls = new JRXlsExporter();
    exporterXls.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT, jasperPrint);
    exporterXls.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.OUTPUT_STREAM, output);
    exporterXls.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.IS_ONE_PAGE_PER_SHEET, Boolean.TRUE);
    exporterXls.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.IS_DETECT_CELL_TYPE, Boolean.TRUE);
    exporterXls.exportReport();
    outputfile.write(output.toByteArray());
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

When i run it, i get the following exception:

```
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: java.net.MalformedURLException
```

Can someone please tell me what did i do wrong and how to fix it. And also tell me where to add the jrxml file.

Comment: Did you tried absolute path for .jrxml file?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a springboot project; try moving report.jrxml into src/main/resources and:

```
InputStream resourceAsStream = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream(reportTemplateUrl);
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot. you should also change the url to "/report.jrxml"

Comment: I tried that also. This time the error is no longer there, but nothing is happening, file is not downloaded.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I do this. Hope this helps

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/ProduceMyReportPDF", method = RequestMethod.GET, params = { "P1" })
public FileSystemResource AnalisiIncassiGS(
        @RequestParam(value = "P1") String p1,
        HttpServletResponse response) {

    try {
        // START of block "using jasper library": try this if you want to produce a PDF using jasper library
        String reportname = "c:\\TEMPLATE\\myreport.jasper";
        JasperReport jasperReport = (JasperReport) JRLoader.loadObject(new File(reportname));
        MyData d = new MyData(); // used to store parameters and datasource
        JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, d.getParametersHashMap(), d.getDataSource);
        JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfFile(jasperPrint, "c:\\outputpath\\p4.pdf");
        // END of block "using jasper library"

        // START of block "using jasper server": ALTERNATIVELY try this if you want to produce a PDF using jasper server installed somewhere
        String sJASPERSERVER_URL = "http://192.168.1.1:8080/jasperserver";
        String sPathToYourReport = "Path/to/your/report/myreport";
        String j_username = "jasperadmin";
        String j_password = "yourpassword";
        URL website = new URL( sJASPERSERVER_URL+sPathToYourReport + ".pdf"+   "?PARAM1="+ p1 +"&j_username="+j_username+"&j_password="+j_password   );

        ReadableByteChannel rbc = Channels.newChannel(website.openStream());
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("c:\\outputpath\\p4.pdf");
        fos.getChannel().transferFrom(rbc, 0, Long.MAX_VALUE);
        // END of block "using jasper server"

        response.setContentType("application/pdf");
        response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=p4.pdf");

        return new FileSystemResource( "c:\\outputpath\\p4.pdf" );

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

        return null;
    }
}
```